# Laravel 5 pagination issues

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm running into issues with the rewritten L5 pagination where previous methods are now missing. Specifically `lastPage()` and `total()`.

1. Was this an oversight (in which case I'm happy to submit an issue / PR)?
2. Should I be able to get through to the Collection and calculate it myself? I believe the old paginator allowed something like this with `__call()`, however `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator.php` doesn't appear to even keep a reference to the full Collection around. It immediately slices the `$items` to match `$perPage`, leaving me no way to calculate a total or lastPage on my own.
3. Should I be using `LengthAwarePaginator` instead? And if so, shouldn't `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::paginate()` return a `LengthAwarePaginator` instead of `Paginator`? I'm trying to paginate a DB collection, and getting an instance of `Paginator` back.

I just want to make sure I understand the thought / direction behind pagination in L5 before I assume there's a bug and submit a GH issue or fix.

**Udate**: Now that Laravel 5 has been released, this is no longer an issue. I get a `LengthAwarePaginator` when I `paginate()` on Builder.

Answer (score 2):

i ran in to the same problem. here is what i did extended the eloquent builder class.
and since i already have model extended, loaded the new builder from there.

you can load the new builder from the extended model like this

```
public function newEloquentBuilder($query)
{
   return new \App\ExtendedBuilder($query);
}
```

bellow i have the extended builder
..................

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class ExtendedBuilder extends Builder{

public function lengthawarepaginate($perPage = null, $columns = ['*'])
{
    $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    $perPage = $perPage ?: $this->model->getPerPage();

    $this->skip(($page - 1) * $perPage)->take($perPage);

    $queryClone = clone ($this->getQuery());

    $total = $queryClone->skip(0)->take($perPage + 1)->count($columns);


    return new LengthAwarePaginator($this->get($columns)->all(),$total, $perPage, $page, [
        'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()
    ]);
}
```

}

[this is where i got the original code from](https://chromabits.com/post/an-update-on-laravel-5-pagination)

not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, now Laravel support pagination total

You could use like this

> $total = $paginatedCollection->total()